Rotate arrow radial axis radarchart chart.js
In reference to an question I asked before.
How to get radar chart coordinates using getValueForDistanceFromCenter with Chart.js?
I would like to rotate the arrow like a clock based on degrees. I can produce the arrow on the endpoint at the bottom of the cricle, but I cannot calculate new end points based on degrees on the circleradius. I tried to use sin and cosinus based on an x-y axis. See code
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arrow(
  xScale.getPixelForValue(0),
  yScale.getPixelForValue(0.0),
  xScale.getPixelForValue(8 * xline90),
  yScale.getPixelForValue(8 * yline90),
  [0, 0.75, -15, 0.75, -15, 10]
);
ctx.fill();

var xline90 = Math.sin((Math.PI * 2 * 120) / 360);
var yline90 = Math.cos((Math.PI * 2 * 120) / 360);

For the radarchart I use getPointPositionForValue, but when I apply the above sinus and cosinus the arrow ends up on a random point on the canvas.
I also tried to use rotate but I also could not get that to work.
Could somebody point me in the right direction? Or is het impossible what I want to do?


    var mobilewidth = 420;
var backgroundcolor = "transparent";

var titleshow = true;
var titletext = [
  "Example"
];
var titleshowmob = true;
var titlecolor = "rgba(75,75,75,1)";
var titlesize = 15;
var titlesizemob = 9;
var titleweight = "600";
var titlefont = "sans-serif";

var anglelinecolor = "rgba(120,120,120,1)";
var anglelinewidth = 2;

var resultcustomer = 4;
var resultoperational = 9;
var resultproduct = 10;

var resultbackgroundcolor = "rgba(247,70,74,0.2)";
var resultlinecolor = "rgba(247,70,74,1)";
var resultlinewidth = 2;
var resultpoint = 2;
var resultpointwidth = 3;

var pointlabelcolor = "rgba(75,75,75,1)";
var pointlabelsize = 15;
var pointlabelsizemob = 9;
var pointlabelweight = "600";
var pointlabelfont = "sans-serif";
var pointlabelalign = "center";
var pointlabelpadding = 10;

var ringbackgroundinner = "rgba(195,195,195,1)";
var ringbackgroundmiddle = "rgba(225,225,225,1)";
var ringbackgroundouter = "rgba(254,254,254,1)";
var ringbordercolor = "rgba(120,120,120,1)";
var ringborderdash = [6, 4];
var ringborderwidth = 1.5;

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var data = {
  labels: [
    ["test"],
    ["test2"],
    ["test3"]
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "nvt",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(38,120,255,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(38,120,255, 1)",
      pointRadius: 0,
      data: [, 0]
    },
    {
      label: "Score",
      data: [resultcustomer, resultproduct, resultoperational],
      borderWidth: resultlinewidth,
      pointRadius: resultpoint,
      pointBorderWidth: resultpointwidth,
      backgroundColor: resultbackgroundcolor,
      borderColor: resultlinecolor
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      display: function () {
        if (window.innerWidth < mobilewidth) {
          return titleshowmob;
        } else {
          return titleshow;
        }
      },
      color: titlecolor,
      font: {
        size: function () {
          if (window.innerWidth < mobilewidth) {
            return titlesizemob;
          } else {
            return titlesize;
          }
        },
        weight: titleweight,
        family: titlefont
      },
      text: titletext
    }
  },
  scales: {
    r: {
      angleLines: {
        color: anglelinecolor,
        borderWidth: anglelinewidth
      },
      pointLabels: {
        color: pointlabelcolor,
        padding: pointlabelpadding,
        font: {
          size: function () {
            if (window.innerWidth < mobilewidth) {
              return pointlabelsizemob;
            } else {
              return pointlabelsize;
            }
          },
          weight: pointlabelweight,
          family: pointlabelfont
        }
      },
      min: 1,
      max: 10,
      ticks: {
        display: false
      },
      grid: {
        display: false,
        circular: true
      }
    }
  }
};

var plugin1 = {
  beforeDraw(chart) {
    var c = chart.ctx;

    c.save();
    c.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    c.fillStyle = backgroundcolor;
    c.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
    c.restore();

    var rScale = chart.scales.r;
    var xline0 = Math.sin(340);
    var yline0 = Math.cos(340);
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.forEach(function (item, index) {
      var circle3 = rScale.getPointPositionForValue(0.5 + index, 10);
      var base = rScale.getPointPositionForValue(0.5 + index, 1);

      c.beginPath();
      c.lineWidth = ringborderwidth;
      c.fillStyle = ringbackgroundouter;
      c.arc(base.x, base.y, circle3.y - base.y, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      c.setLineDash(ringborderdash);
      c.strokeStyle = ringbordercolor;
      c.stroke();
      c.fill();

      c.save();
      c.beginPath();
      c.fillStyle = "black";
      c.arrow(base.x, base.y, circle3.x, circle3.y, [
        0,
        5,
        -15,
        5,
        -15,
        10
      ]);

      c.fill();
      c.restore();

    });
  }
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "radar",
  data: data,
  options: options,
  plugins: [plugin1]
});
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://frogcat.github.io/canvas-arrow/canvas-arrow.js"></script>
<html>
<canvas id="myChart" />

</html>




To find the end point of the arrow (arrowEnd), when you have the position of the center (base)
and of the bottom of the circle (6 o'clock - circle3) and the angle of rotation
in degrees (presumed to start from the top of the circle, 12 o'clock) you have to
find the vector difference from circle3 and base (I used the variable circleFromBase),
rotate that vector
by the angle (-angle + 180) in radians and then translate back to base:
const angle = 340; // rotate the arrow angle degrees clockwise
const alpha = angle * Math.PI/180 - Math.PI; // angle converted to radians and measured from top (12 o'clock)
chart.data.datasets[0].data.forEach(function (item, index) {
    const base = rScale.getPointPositionForValue(0.5 + index, 1);
    const circle3 = rScale.getPointPositionForValue(0.5 + index, 10);
    const circleFromBase = {x: circle3.x - base.x, y: circle3.y - base.y};
    const arrowEnd = { // rotation of -alpha (clockwise) + translation to base
        x: circleFromBase.x * Math.cos(alpha) - circleFromBase.y * Math.sin(alpha) + base.x,
        y: circleFromBase.x * Math.sin(alpha) + circleFromBase.y * Math.cos(alpha) + base.y
    };
    // ........................
}

Applied to your snippet:


var mobilewidth = 420;
var backgroundcolor = "transparent";

var titleshow = true;
var titletext = [
  "Example"
];
var titleshowmob = true;
var titlecolor = "rgba(75,75,75,1)";
var titlesize = 15;
var titlesizemob = 9;
var titleweight = "600";
var titlefont = "sans-serif";

var anglelinecolor = "rgba(120,120,120,1)";
var anglelinewidth = 2;

var resultcustomer = 4;
var resultoperational = 9;
var resultproduct = 10;

var resultbackgroundcolor = "rgba(247,70,74,0.2)";
var resultlinecolor = "rgba(247,70,74,1)";
var resultlinewidth = 2;
var resultpoint = 2;
var resultpointwidth = 3;

var pointlabelcolor = "rgba(75,75,75,1)";
var pointlabelsize = 15;
var pointlabelsizemob = 9;
var pointlabelweight = "600";
var pointlabelfont = "sans-serif";
var pointlabelalign = "center";
var pointlabelpadding = 10;

var ringbackgroundinner = "rgba(195,195,195,1)";
var ringbackgroundmiddle = "rgba(225,225,225,1)";
var ringbackgroundouter = "rgba(254,254,254,1)";
var ringbordercolor = "rgba(120,120,120,1)";
var ringborderdash = [6, 4];
var ringborderwidth = 1.5;

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var data = {
  labels: [
    ["test"],
    ["test2"],
    ["test3"]
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "nvt",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(38,120,255,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(38,120,255, 1)",
      pointRadius: 0,
      data: [, 0]
    },
    {
      label: "Score",
      data: [resultcustomer, resultproduct, resultoperational],
      borderWidth: resultlinewidth,
      pointRadius: resultpoint,
      pointBorderWidth: resultpointwidth,
      backgroundColor: resultbackgroundcolor,
      borderColor: resultlinecolor
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      display: function () {
        if (window.innerWidth < mobilewidth) {
          return titleshowmob;
        } else {
          return titleshow;
        }
      },
      color: titlecolor,
      font: {
        size: function () {
          if (window.innerWidth < mobilewidth) {
            return titlesizemob;
          } else {
            return titlesize;
          }
        },
        weight: titleweight,
        family: titlefont
      },
      text: titletext
    }
  },
  scales: {
    r: {
      angleLines: {
        color: anglelinecolor,
        borderWidth: anglelinewidth
      },
      pointLabels: {
        color: pointlabelcolor,
        padding: pointlabelpadding,
        font: {
          size: function () {
            if (window.innerWidth < mobilewidth) {
              return pointlabelsizemob;
            } else {
              return pointlabelsize;
            }
          },
          weight: pointlabelweight,
          family: pointlabelfont
        }
      },
      min: 1,
      max: 10,
      ticks: {
        display: false
      },
      grid: {
        display: false,
        circular: true
      }
    }
  }
};

var plugin1 = {
  beforeDraw(chart) {
    var c = chart.ctx;

    c.save();
    c.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    c.fillStyle = backgroundcolor;
    c.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
    c.restore();

    var rScale = chart.scales.r;
    var angle = 340; // rotate the arrow angle degrees clockwise from 12 o'clock
    var alpha = angle * Math.PI/180 - Math.PI; // angle converted to radians and measured from top (12 o'clock)
    
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.forEach(function (item, index) {
      var circle3 = rScale.getPointPositionForValue(0.5 + index, 10);
      var base = rScale.getPointPositionForValue(0.5 + index, 1);
      var circleFromBase = {x: circle3.x - base.x, y: circle3.y - base.y};
      
      var arrowEnd = { // rotation of -alpha (clockwise) + translation to base
                x: circleFromBase.x * Math.cos(alpha) - circleFromBase.y * Math.sin(alpha) + base.x,
                y: circleFromBase.x * Math.sin(alpha) + circleFromBase.y * Math.cos(alpha) + base.y
            };

      c.beginPath();
      c.lineWidth = ringborderwidth;
      c.fillStyle = ringbackgroundouter;
      c.arc(base.x, base.y, circle3.y - base.y, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      c.setLineDash(ringborderdash);
      c.strokeStyle = ringbordercolor;
      c.stroke();
      c.fill();

      c.save();
      c.beginPath();
      c.fillStyle = "black";
      c.arrow(base.x, base.y, arrowEnd.x, arrowEnd.y, [
        0,
        5,
        -15,
        5,
        -15,
        10
      ]);

      c.fill();
      c.restore();

    });
  }
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "radar",
  data: data,
  options: options,
  plugins: [plugin1]
});
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://frogcat.github.io/canvas-arrow/canvas-arrow.js"></script>
<html>
<canvas id="myChart" />

</html>




Thanx Kikon, It works fantastic!
